Unity .dll startup loading Time Issue
I am having few sdks like Polkadot and some other dependencies which have dll files stored in the plugins directory of my unity projects.
The problem that I am facing is when i make a build and launch the app on phone, it takes more than 10 seconds to even show the "Made with Unity" splash screen.
I belive this is happening due to a lot of dlls getting loaded at runtime. Can anyone help me how I can sort this issue? Tried removing or renaming the dll files from plugin folder but that is causing obvious runtime dependency issues and errors.
I tried addressable.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
